# Shortcut to "Select all" in Windows 7 Command Prompt?

Tags: command-line, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there any shortcut to *Edit -> Select all* in command prompt in Windows 7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try Right-click > Select All.

Comment: That's actually a simple and effective idea! Thanks.